# Datepicker is not showing in Internet explorer 8

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I have used used struts-2 for my apllication and for creating datepicker i have used the "struts-jquery-tags"...it works fine in other browser but in Internet explorer, it is not showing at all..My code goes here

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<sj:head/>
<sj:datepicker name="dueDate" id="dueDate" displayFormat="mm/dd/yy" label="Due Date" changeMonth="true" changeYear="true" title="Due Date" showButtonPanel="true" maxlength="10" readonly="true" buttonImage="/BPELServiceInvoke/resources/images/calendar_add.png" buttonImageOnly="true" duration="fast"  />
```

Comment: Is this the browser compatibility related or what is the question then if it works fine with versions that supported jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This is strictly related to browser compatiblity issues for that plugin.

Best way would be to post here : https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/DatePickerTag

Meanwhile, just try downgrading the version of plugin you're using. I'm sure the older-versions will be having support for IE8.

Also, look at the change-log for jquery version being used and it's support for IE8 - https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/Changelog